# What's the "cdl" do in TOKENMATCHES[cdl]?

Tags: syntax, nspredicate

I came across TOKENMATCHES in minute 31 of [Introducing CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/208/) and was curious, so I did a google search and found very little about it outside of [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155215/cloudkit-unexpected-expression-for-nspredicate).

```
NSPredicate(format: "ALL tokenize(%@, 'Cdl') IN allTokens", "after session")
```

Actually, confusing things further, that post uses different syntax than the WWDC video:

```
NSPredicate(format: "allTokens TOKENMATCHES[cdl] %@", "bob smith")
```

As I understand it, these queries return any records that have all of the tokenized string arguments within one or more text fields. The latter case would fetch a record with, say, `person.name = "bob"` and `person.last = "smith"`, as well as, say, a record where `person.note = "Bob likes Joseph Smith."`. (Corrections welcome.)

All that said, this question isn't about the full predicate, but just that `cdl` (or `Cdl`?) parameter/modifier/whateverthehellitis.

**TL;DR—What's `cdl` mean, and are there other values that can go in that "slot" of the format string?**

---

**<rant>** *Why isn't the [predicate syntax documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) comprehensive? It's as if Apple's managers are scared of the mysterious, ancient power that is NSPredicate; none dare assign the technical writer and engineer needed to make this otherwise simple class accessible to the Rest of Us™. A Google search for ["nspredicate TOKENMATCHES"](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=nspredicate%20TOKENMATCHES&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=nspredicate%20%22TOKENMATCHES%22) gives only 8 results, none of which are at apple.com.*  **</rant>**

Comment: `[c] case insensitive: lowercase & uppercase values are treated the same, [d] diacritic insensitive: special characters treated as the base character`. It's told like this in Apple doc: "String comparisons are, by default, case and diacritic sensitive. You can modify an operator using the key characters c and d within square braces to specify case and diacritic insensitivity respectively, for example firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] $FIRST_NAME." For the `l`, I don't know. You can use them with `CONTAINS`: `CONTAINS[cd]`and others.

Comment: Ah, sure, that makes sense. Feel free to repost as an answer if you want the points. Otherwise just…thanks!

Comment: I'm still wondering what means `l`. When I find out, I'll think that the answer may be complete. Until then, I'll keep looking times to times.

Comment: More than 1 year later, reading by chance this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473973/nspredicate-case-insensitive-matching-on-to-many-relationship#comment52500315_1594822 talking about  a `NSDiacriticInsensitivePredicateOption` issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, at least!

The doc: [NSComparisonPredicateOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscomparisonpredicateoptions)

```
typedef enum NSComparisonPredicateOptions : NSUInteger {
    NSCaseInsensitivePredicateOption = 0x01,      //==> [c]
    NSDiacriticInsensitivePredicateOption = 0x02, //==> [d]
    NSNormalizedPredicateOption = 0x04            //==> [n]
} NSComparisonPredicateOptions;

+ NSLocaleSensitivePredicateOption                //==> [l]
```

So basically :
`[c]`: uppercase is the same as lowercase (ie: A == a)
`[d]`: char with [diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) (acute accent, cedilla, etc.) is the same as char without it (ie à == a (accent)
`[l]`: it's for localized specificities. The Apple sample is with "straße" and "strasse" using the German "double s" ([Eszett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F)) as an example.