# Fetching data from core data predicate issue because of character set

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I'm fetching songs name from core data like this case insensitive.

```
predicateText = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText)
```

The issue is that when i'm searching for example

> Can't live without you

the

> Can't

apostrophe in some of the songs is written using a different character set. Some times the apostrophe was written in arabic character set and sometimes in english letters. So not all songs are being fetched correctly.

My be there is a different expression for this to fetch the name of the song independent of the character set used for it?

I'm asking this question because in the Android version of the app it is working correctly regardless the character set of the letters.

Comment: Maybe with others options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961555/whats-the-cdl-do-in-tokenmatchescdl or the `TOKENMATCHES` (I don't know what it does yet exactly)?

Comment: @Larme thanks will test that now

Comment: You could transform the `searchText` before applying the predicate (for example replace apostrophes and other characters with `?`) and use a `LIKE`. Something similar to `name LIKE[cd] %@` for a `searchTerm = "Can?t*"`. But I'm sure that there is a better way than this.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this question on [apple stack exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299505/ios-11-default-quotation-mark-changed-to-and)

Actually all this was because starting iOS 11 they changed the default apostrophe and quotations marks from this `'` and `"` to this `’` and `”`

I had no solution but to replace the apostrophe from the `json` file I'm downloading from the server before saving it to core data. So when a user searches with the new iOS default keyboard apostrophe can find the songs he is searching for.

```
name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name).replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "’")
artist = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .artist).replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "’")
```